# Django Nginx Gunicorn Upstream Premature closed connection while reading response

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

nginx conf

```
server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name private.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    client_body_buffer_size 8000M;
    client_body_timeout 120;
    proxy_connect_timeout 900s;
    proxy_read_timeout 900s;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    autoindex on;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/dm/stat.cok;
    }
}
```

gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target


[Service]
User=Pa
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/un/foldername
ExecStart=/home/un/foldername/bin/gunicorn \
        --access-logfile - \
        --workers 3 \
        --timeout 450 \
        --bind unix:/home/dm/stat.sock scistat.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I upload a large excel file 90mb size, It contains 450000+ rows and 6 columns. After the file upload, It calculate the row and columnf of excel file the multiply it to compute the total row and column of excel file, but this error show **"upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream"**

Comment: How long before it fails? To match to one of timeout settings.

Comment: Also, no reason to set  `proxy_connect_timeout` more than 75s.

Comment: @OlegRusskin, takes 5 minutes calculating the row and columns of excel file then 502 bad gateway error appear and check the error in nginx, show upstream prematurely closed connection.

Comment: @OlegRusskin proxy_connect_timeout is 75s maximum?

Comment: Recommended [proxy_connect_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like **long-running synchronous request** - user uploads large file, it is being processed in the view which takes significant amount of time and only after a response to user's request is sent back.

While processing file where is no response back to user and gunicorn worker is killed due to timeout. To verify this - try increasing timeout in gunicorn to 900 or higher (then if may be terminated by exceeding nginx proxy_read_timeout).

---

It is best **not to increase gunicorn timeout** far from default 30s (unless really required) - try removing / lowering timeout and modifying code as below.

Leave **only file saving / basic validation logic in upload view** - return response as fast as possible after file was uploaded to server.

Use [**Celery**](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) to run long-running / periodic / async tasks in separate celery workers - like processing / calculating uploaded file.

Separate endpoints / views can be made to get status info of uploaded file or results.

---

View processing time should be as little as possible - it greatly affects user experience. If user needs to wait longer than few seconds for response after making a request - that is not good. If it takes minutes - good luck. Long-running operations better be performed in async way - and

Comment: Ok Thanks, I'll try your advice.